# Mysql Master-Master with additional slaves

Tags: mysql, replication

We have two datacenters with a copy of our web app (online training platform) at each. The primary datacenter receives all of the traffic at any given time and the second datacenter serves as a failover(using DNS failover). The databases are set up in master-master with different auto-increment-increment values. The server at datacenter 1 also has its own local slave server on which we do backups, that way we can pause replication, do the backup with mysqldump, then start replication again.

```
 SERVER 1 <=========> SERVER 2
    |
  Slave 1
```

This weekend we did a failover to server 2 because datacenter 1 was doing planned network maintenance. Everything went smoothly and after a few hours we brought everything back to DC1. Last night I start getting replication errors on the slave saying it failed to DELETE an entry that didn't exist. I found it odd that the Slave 1 was getting the error while Server 2 was not (since they're both acting as slaves to Server 1). After digging, I found out that we still have a user that's going to Server 2.. for whatever reason their DNS hasn't updated for over 2 days. So the new data that they are producing is being replicated to Server 1, but Slave 1 is not getting these updates because they're not in Server 1's binlogs.

I now see that this was poor planning on my part for not foreseeing this issue. My question is, how can I make this work? We want to keep the master-master and we want to allow Slave 1 to exist, not only for backups but for additional read only reporting servers and such. **Those of you that run Master-Master, what have you done to remedy similar issues?** Or is this just a bad setup and I'm SOL? The app was not built with redundancy in mind, so everything is having to be done system side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `server1` to binlog not only its own updates, but also those updates he received from `server2`, so that `slave1` will get all updates.

You just need to tell `server1` to do this, which can be accomplished by setting [`log-slave-updates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) to yes.

You might want to set this option on `server2` too, if the server topology should change someday (as Rolando kindly remarked in the comments below).

This does not loop endlessly as the default setting for [`replicate-same-server-id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-same-server-id) is `0` (and cannot be changed as long as `log-slave-updates` is on). This setting set to 0 means the slave will skip statements he receives with his own server-id.

Your infrastructure decision in general seems fine to me.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. +1 for typing faster than me.!!!

Comment: I would also recommend server2 have log-slave-updates should the topology need to be reversed.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Sounds good. I updated my answer with this hint.

Comment: Wouldn't that create an infinite loop of sorts in a master-master setup? If data goes into server B and gets replicated to A, then A writes that to its binlogs as well, won't B then pick up those changes from the binlog and try to execute them to it's own dataset?

Comment: @Safado No, this works fine. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great. These were the answers I needed to hear. Thank you for the suggestions.